# JavaScript list all members in discord server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So im trying to make a command that lists all the members in a discord server but it doesnt seem to be working. I did research, tried different methods and none seem to work. This is the code im working with right now.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();    
bot.on("message", async msg => {
if (msg.author.id !== config.id) return;

let content = msg.content;
let text = content.toLowerCase();
let author = msg.author;
let member = msg.member;
let args = content.split(" ").slice(1);
let argsLower = text.split(" ");
let command = argsLower[0].replace(prefix, "");

if (!msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

if (command === "listmembers"){
    msg.delete();
   msg.channel.guild.fetchMembers().then(guild =>{
      console.log("test");
      guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
    } );
}
```

i tried console logging "test" in the function but that doesnt show up in console so i cant seem to get into the function.

Comment: Please define "doesn't seem to be working".  Have you put in breakpoints, console logs, or done anything to try and debug?  Are you able to get into the function you tried?  Please provide more information about what is or isn't working.

Comment: `const bot = new Discord.Client();` <-- ??? why define a *new* bot inside your bot's message function? I'm not sure how that could possibly make any sense, also, it should be giving you an error and not running any of your code.

Comment: thats meant to be on top i dont know how it got there.

Comment: try `console.log(msg.content)`, `console.log(command)`, etc outside of your if-statement. stuff like that should be your first step: "why isn't my code running?" --> check that all variables have the values you expect, if they don't, the code may never enter your if-statement!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to console.log() all of the members, it's just:

```
message.guild.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```

but if you're trying to list them out into chat you need to:

```
var list = [];
message.guild.members.forEach(member => list.push(member.user.username));
message.reply(`Total members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
const embed4 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor(0x684dad)
.setTitle('Member List:')
.setDescription(list);
message.channel.send(embed4);
```

You can customize it as you wish but that's just an example.